# Can't log into any user account

Tags: login, damage

I had a bit of water damage incident with my MBP 13 (mid 2014). Apple have quoted me £1250 to replace the flash storage, the top board and the logic board so obviously it's a write off in that regard.

I've since done all of the SOP regarding drying it out etc and it has eventually turned on. The majority of the keyboard inputs completely the wrong character and the trackpad isn't functional. However, external mice and keyboards work fine so I thought I'd log in to grab a couple of bits off of it which weren't in dropbox/github/cloud of any description.

I can't log in with either of the administrative accounts, both of which I definitely know the passwords for.

I have booted into recovery mode with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys, and used the disk utility to unlock and mount the drive, then the terminal to run `resetpassword` and use the dialog to both reset the password and repair the home directories to no avail.

I can't boot into single user mode because I have filevault enabled and I can't revert the decryption- it errors* and exits.

I have tried creating a new account but I get errors about the path. I'm honestly not sure if I'm doing it wrong or if there are actually some errors with the paths. I haven't pursued this avenue much further than that.

I can't understand why I am unable to log into either of the accounts. If anyone can provide any insight that'd be much appreciated.

<sup>* *I can't post the filevault error at this point because I'm not at that machine currently but will add if anyone asks.*</sup>

Comment: I would try putting that SSD into an [external enclosure](http://amzn.to/2emL0tF), connecting it to a different Mac and try to boot that way.  You should be attempting to do data recovery on a "good" machine, not a compromised one.

Comment: In an attempt to prove that it's the machine causing the failed login or just to get my data back? I have ordered the screwdrivers to open the mac so I can't do this yet. I've used `scp` to copy my data off already so it's more a case of seeing if it works before I wipe it. I can't work out why all the user accounts would just stop working.